# (SwiftUI) NavigationBar height issue

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I have to use large title (navigationBarTitleDisplayMode = .large) and .searchable in View 2.

But in that case, the height of the navigation bar in View 3 is set strangely.

I think, the sum of the height of the navigation bar and the height of the search bar in View 2 is applied to the height of the navigation bar in View 3.

Is there a way to set the height of the navigation bar in view 3 to the height it would have when .inline?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink("View 2") {
                        SecondView()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("View 1")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("View 3") {
                    ThirdView()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("View 2")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        .searchable(text: $text)
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 3")
            .navigationTitle("View 3")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the first and second `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)` & change your .searchable to `.searchable(text: $text, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))` it should work.

Tested and working code:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    init() {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .red
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink("View 2") {
                    SecondView()
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("View 1")
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {

    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink("View 3") {
                ThirdView()
            }
        }.navigationTitle("View 2")
        .searchable(text: $text, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("View 3")
        .navigationTitle("View 3")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine with NavigationStack, but still has problems with NavigationView. Since I have to set the minimum supported version to 15, it seems difficult to use NavigationStack.

Comment: Setting the navigationViewStyle to .stack solved the problem . I guess I'll have to do some more research as to why. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @n3bular great to hear! And a happy new code year :)