# How to change height of NavigationBar

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar

[image]

My NavigationBar has gone large. How do you control the height in SwiftUI?

The relevant code is:

```
 .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(false)
 .navigationBarTitle("Sunrise Sunset", displayMode: .inline)
 .navigationBarColor(backgroundColor: .gray, titleColor: .white)
```

There seems to be a similar question on this topic but I couldn't get it to work:
[(SwiftUI) NavigationBar height issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74570361/swiftui-navigationbar-height-issue)

The .navigationBarColor struct comes from 56505528.

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505528/swiftui-update-navigation-bar-title-color

struct NavigationBarModifier: ViewModifier {
    var backgroundColor: UIColor?
    var titleColor: UIColor?
    init(backgroundColor: UIColor?, titleColor: UIColor?) {
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        let coloredAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        coloredAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        coloredAppearance.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        coloredAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: titleColor ?? .white]
        coloredAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: titleColor ?? .white]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = coloredAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = coloredAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = coloredAppearance
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack{
            content
            VStack {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color(self.backgroundColor ?? .clear)
                        .frame(height: geometry.safeAreaInsets.top)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

 
extension View {
    func navigationBarColor(backgroundColor: UIColor?, titleColor: UIColor?) -> some View {
        self.modifier(NavigationBarModifier(backgroundColor: backgroundColor, titleColor: titleColor))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The NavigationStack! If you have a complex View and your NavigationBar has oversized it can mean that your structures aren't contained/paired correctly.

I changed "NavigationStack" to a "VStack" just to see if the page rendered OK and the NavigationBar went back to its normal, thin size.

Try this if you're having the same issue.